# How to draw media details for Isotope gallery using Photoswipe

Tags: php, functions, images, gallery

I am currently in the process of making a Wordpress gallery that draws directly from the Media Library and incorporates Isotope and Photoswipe. Using a modified version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22032833), I have successfully added the attachments to a page template and then restricted the display to categories (with categories for media attachments).

My issue now is further refining the display...

As I am using `wp_get_attachment_image` in my function (so I can define the image size), rather than `wp_get_attachment_url`, I can't get the `href` working. In addition to this, I need to define the full image size within the `data-size` of the `href`.

I'm also trying to draw the image title and caption, as well as apply the categories of each image as classes to the containing `div`.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function get_images_from_media_library() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' =>'image',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => 25,
        'category_name' => 'artwork',
    );
    $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
    $images = array();
    foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
        $images[]= wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'full' );
    }
    return $images;
}

function display_images_from_media_library() {

    $imgs = get_images_from_media_library();
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
    $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
    $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
    $html = '<section class="isotope-wrap">
              <div class="isotope gallery" data-pswp-uid="1">
                <div class="isotope-sizer"></div>';

    foreach($imgs as $img) {
        $html .= '<div class="isotope-item"><figure>
                  <a href="' . $url . '" data-size="">' . $img . '</a>
                  <figcaption class="wp-caption-text"><h2>' . $image_title . '</h2>
                  <p>' . $caption . '</p></figcaption></figure></div>';
    }

    $html .= '</div>';

    return $html;

}
```

Finally, I'm also trying to build a filter group for the Isotope gallery, using the image categories as the labels. Here is the code I have so far, which doesn't seem to be working since my categories are not counting the images (all categories show a count of 0):

```
$terms = get_terms('category', array('parent' => 'artwork'));
                      $count = count($terms);
                        if ( $count > 0 ){
                          foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-dark'  data-hover='" . $term->name . "' data-filter='." . $term->slug . "'>" . $term->name . "</button>\n";
                          }
                        }
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT** I added the following code:

```
function get_image_urls_from_media_library() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' =>'image',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'category_name' => 'artwork',
    );
    $query_images = new WP_Query( $args );
    $urls = array();
    foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
        $urls[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
    }
    return $urls;
}
```

and added a nested `foreach`, which is drawing a valid `href`. Unfortunately, however, it's only drawing the first attachment entry and all images in the gallery are linking to that same first image. The images are also duplicated 5 times on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I had a scenario very similar to yours. I trust these notes can help.

1 - When querying a custom taxonomy, wp_query requires a more information.
[The codex reference is here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)
The information is in this form.

```
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bob',
        ),
    ),
```

In your case, I believe that the taxonomy is "artwork". I found that using the field value of 'slug' is good; I leave it to you to know what your term is.

2 - In your revised function, you dropped the "posts_per_page" parameter. That's your choice but be aware that if you don't declare it then WP-Query will return a maximum of 10 records. If you were expecting more images then this could be the answer.

3 - In your function "*display_images_from_media_library*", the second line is:

"$url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );".

In this case, $image is an undefined variable. Since $image is a variable from your function "*get_images_from_media_library*", I'll hazard a guess that at some stage you had a single function for getting the image information and then displaying it; but when you split the single function into two, you probably didn't notice this line.

4 - Your code to create the filters starts with the top level (the parent level) - that fine, but I believe that the filters are actually the children not the parents. In essence, there's another foreach required (details below).

5 - In addition to the above, you have made your initial focus the "attachment URL". But I suggest it might be more productive to concentrate on getting the post/attachment ID from the WP_Query, and use this as a means to get all the other fields that you need to display. In fact, if you create an array based on $posts, you'll automatically get the caption and the title as a by-product.

I found the following to work. Obviously you need to substitute the relevant Taxonomy and term in each of the functions.

```
function gallery_get_images_from_media_library(){
    $g_myargs = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' =>'image/jpeg',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'posts_per_page' => 25,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'media_category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'edition-covers',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $g_myquery_images = new WP_Query( $g_myargs );

    $g_posts = $g_myquery_images->posts;

    $html = '<section class="isotope-wrap">
              <div class="isotope gallery" data-pswp-uid="1">
                <div class="isotope-sizer"></div>';

    foreach ($g_posts as $g_img) {

        $url = wp_get_attachment_url($g_img->ID);

        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($g_img->ID,'full');

        $image_title = $g_img->post_title;

        $caption = $g_img->post_excerpt;

        $html .= '<div class="isotope-item"><figure>
                        <a href="'.$url.'">
                        <img src="'.$src[0] .'"></a>
                        <figcaption class="wp-caption-text">
                        <h2>' . $image_title . '</h2>
                        <p>' . $caption . '</p>
                        </figcaption></figure></div>';
    }

    $html .= '</div>';

return $html;
}
```

To display the images I just added the following code in my template page.

```
$imgs = gallery_get_images_from_media_library();
echo $imgs;
```

---

```
function gallery_make_filters(){

    // starting row of the filter = show all
    $gallery_filter_content = '<button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">show all</button>'. PHP_EOL ;

    // get the cover terms for parent terms with a count>0
    $gallery_parentterms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'reviewcovers',
        'parent' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    // if there are parent covers with children
    if (is_array($gallery_parentterms)) {

        // break down for each parent
        foreach($gallery_parentterms as $gallery_obj) {

            // get the children covers 
            $gallery_childterms = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'reviewcovers',
                'child_of' => $gallery_obj->term_id,
                'hide_empty' => true,
            ));

            // test for content of childterms
            if (is_array($gallery_childterms)) {

            // create a filter for each child.
            foreach($gallery_childterms as $gallery_object) {   

                    // build the filters for each non-zero child term
                    // filter is progressively incremented.
                    $gallery_filter_content .= '<button class="button" data-filter="'.".".$gallery_object->slug.'">'.$gallery_object->description.'</button>'. PHP_EOL;

                } // end of foreach-children array

            } // end of if children array

        } //end of foreach parent array

    }// end of if - parent array
    else 
    {
    echo 'no results';
    }

return $gallery_filter_content;

}
```

To display the filters, insert the following code in the page template.

```
$filters = gallery_make_filters();
echo $filters;
```

---

Lastly, and not wanting to be accused of 'teaching you how to suck eggs', I find that every so often one or more lines of my code don't work as expected (probably because I am not such a great coder). In any event, when this does happen, I find it useful to display the contents of an array or a variable so that I can work out just where the code is coming undone.

These few lines are my mainstays. I just 'unremark' the lines, update the array/variable name, save, update the site.
1 - for an array

```
//echo "<pre>";print_r($gallery_childterms);echo "</pre>"; //DEBUG - a readable form of vardump
//echo "<p>end of print_r gallery_childterms</p>"; //DEBUG-this is so I know whether and what has printed.
```

2 - for a variable

```
//echo "the src is ".$src."</br>"; // DEBUG - the line break is so that consecutive lines will make sense.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your input -- I trust this worked in your situation. I haven't yet had a chance to implement this into my own, but I will be sure to let you know the outcome once I do get a chance. You've given a lot of detail and, addressing your final point of 'teaching me to suck eggs', I could never accuse you of such, since I'm still feeling my way through this confusing language they call PHP.